# Why am I getting PL/SQL trigger error PLS-00103?

Tags: plsql, triggers

I've written a trigger to not update a table's field if it already has some value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DO_NOT_UPDATE BEFORE UPDATE ON CONCERNED_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :OLD.CONCERNED_FIELD IS NOT NULL 
   THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20182,'Concerned dataitem already exists!');
   END IF;
END;
```

I'm getting this error on compiling it:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/3      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
         one of the following:
         ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
```

What looks to be the problem? I'm completely overlooking something.

Comment: Alright, solved.

It was missing a / symbol in the line next to the final END;

Comment: Didn't you get any error for not using the `REFERENCING` clause?